# Error in same project in another machine

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, web-applications, vraptor

im just trying to run a test project, but i cant understand why it return this errors, its the same computer configuration

Firewall OFF
Eclipse Kepler SR1 32bits (the same in the other computer)
JRE7 32bits 
JDK7 32bits 
Maven 3.2.1
JBoss from Eclipse Market

i just imported the zip but look the errors:
 https://i.stack.imgur.com/lphI3.png
[image]

where it ask for the vraptor-jpa, the version in this pom is the same that is working in this project in other machine, why it has a lot of errors for the SAME THING?

solved some problems by removing the reference to a old .jar and deleting the .m2 folder, not i ended with this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/gRFll.png
[image]

Answer (score 0):

looks like your `.classpath` has some invalid reference to jar (which doesn't exist), open your `<PROJECT_ROOT>/.classpath` file and correct invalid references or you can do it with eclipse interface, `right click > properties > java build path > fix those invalid entries`

Comment: thanks, this solved the problem of the vraptor-jpa, but the others ERRORs still

Comment: other error says you don't have `servlet-api` present in classpat, add the dependency for `javax.servlet:servlet-api` in your `pom.xml`

Comment: in the other machine its the same pom, and dont have the servlet-api reference, why i need to add in this one? 
look my second image in the edited post

Comment: may be in other eclipse you have suppressed jsp errors  ?

Comment: Try cleaning out the local artifact repository on the machine that is failing.  Let Maven re-download everything.  This often works.